# How do you edit the bootstrap slide.tmpl when using Nikola themes?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mako

I'm new to Nikola and WedDev for that matter.

I want to edit the slide show to add a radius to the edges of a slide show within the bootstrap3 theme.

I've edited the Bootstrap3 Mako silde.tmpl to added a radius but no luck?

```
<div id="${carousel_id}" class="carousel slide">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
% for i in range(len(content)):
    % if i == 0:
        <li data-target="#${carousel_id}" data-slide-to="${i}" class="active"></li>
    % else:
        <li data-target="#${carousel_id}" data-slide-to="${i}"></li>
    % endif
% endfor
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    % for i, image in enumerate(content):
        % if i == 0:
            <div class="item active"><img src="${image}" alt="" style="border-radius:10px;margin:auto;"></div>
        % else:
            <div class="item"><img src="${image}" alt="" style="border-radius:10px;margin:auto;"></div>
        % endif
    % endfor
</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#${carousel_id}" data-slide="prev"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#${carousel_id}" data-slide="next"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>
```

I've also tried creating new theme with the parent file set to inherit Bootstrap3 but still no luck.

What I'm I missing here? Is this done is CSS or something?

Please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Ah, I went into the CSS and now I have a radius but there's still an ugly 90 degree angle masking my pretty curves.